# Image is not being picked of my gallery: Failure delivering resultInfo

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pick picture of my gallery I can access my Gallery but after clicking the image the app crashed.
I try to debug it and it crashed in the `onActivityResult` method at this line `InputStream openInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoLocation);`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY) {
            Uri photoLocation = data.getData();
            try {

                InputStream openInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoLocation);

                selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openInputStream);
                imagePlantsearch.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your logcat clearly says that you need to add `read external storage` permission to your manifest file.

Comment: Write permission to AndroidManifest.xml file for reading file

Comment: Please add next time the logcat output as text and not as an image.

Comment: I tried to add it as text but the log file  is being saved empty without contains on the desktop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to write permission for reading files from device. Just add below line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**Add Read Permission to Manifest File.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you have read your error carefully. It was already suggested by it to add permission to Manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

insert permission first in your manifest and then add following code..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

add this code

```
@Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
        img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    }
}
}
```